# Jquery slider uneven steps and formatting

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to achieve this exact result:

[Adjustable Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbQLO.jpg)

In other words, I need a Jquery slider with this uneven steps code...

```
var steps = [0, 2000, 3000, 5000, 7500, 10000, 15000, 20000, 300000];

$("#slider").slider({
range: "min",
value: 0,
min: 0,
max: steps.length,
step: 1,
slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#amount").text(steps[ui.value]);
}
});
```

... Included with the code below that performs the $ and separator. How do I do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/emphase/r4tvxucx/2/

Thanks alot!

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve? what is supposed to be the steps array?

Comment: I’m trying to build a range slider where the user answers the following question: how much assets do you own? The min is 0$ and max $50,000,000. The problem is that with even increments it makes the person answering the question feel poor. That’s why I would like to have an uneven increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expanded on your code with the fiddle you provided.  I just added the call to `addCommas()` to the `slide` callback.

I also added an array `initSteps` to initialize the range slider's min and max values.  The values are the indexed which correspond to the value in the `steps` array.

```js
var steps = [0, 2000, 3000, 5000, 7500, 10000, 15000, 20000, 300000]; // Uneven step values
var initSteps = [1, 2]; // Index to value in steps for initializing the range slider

$("#slider").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: steps.length-1,
    step: 1,
    values: initSteps,
    slide:function(event, ui){
        $("#amount1").val("$" + addCommas(steps[ui.values[0]].toString()));
        $("#amount2").val("$" + addCommas(steps[ui.values[1]].toString()));
    }
});

$("#amount1").val("$" + addCommas(steps[initSteps[0]].toString()));
$("#amount2").val("$" + addCommas(steps[initSteps[1]].toString()));

function addCommas(nStr)
{
 nStr += '';
 x = nStr.split('.');
 x1 = x[0];
 x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
 var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
 while (rgx.test(x1)) {
  x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
 }
 return x1 + x2;
}
```

```css
body {padding: 50px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>
<div class="priceContainer">
    <div class="left">
        <label for="amount1">Min Price: </label>
        <input type="text" id="amount1" name="minPrice" style="border: 0; color: #3D80E9; background:#F2F2F2; font-weight: bold;" />
        <br />
        <label for="amount2">Max Price: </label>
        <input type="text" id="amount2" name="maxPrice" style="border: 0; color: #3D80E9; background:#F2F2F2; font-weight: bold;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: user9263373

This seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thanks alot you are a god!

Comment: @FrancoisLepage  I just updated it with a range slider initializing min and max values.  If this is what you need then upvote an mark as the correct answer.